# House chores teacher app

Tags: android, accessibility

I am looking for a house chores teacher app. Here is how it would look in the clothes folding section:

There would be a collection of images for teaching children and disabled or cognitive impaired users clothes folding techniques

I am not sure whether this post would be better suited for the Home Improvement stack exchange.

I am looking for sequences of info graphics for how to fold clothes, illustrating both of the following:

all the different steps required in folding, including configurations of the body positions during folding and presence of support objects

different ways of folding the same piece of clothes

This should be useful to young learners and people with cognitive impairment, as well as various physical impairments, and novices alike.

The clothes items should be t-shirts, sweaters, undershirts, skirts, socks, stockings, underwear, jeans and pants, and so forth.

I have seen a few posts on Instagram, but they seemed to be aimed at showing how to do things quickly, and with skill (skill, that most novice users, won't have).

The charts should also be useful to children that have trouble learning from their parents or teachers.

Thank you for your support.

It is very valuable.

I will be very thankful for your posts, and I'm sure that anyone reading those, can also give back, by putting into practice, and impressing upon others what they face learned.

Thank you for your help.

If an app were available to teach people how to fold clothes, it would be very useful.

The same goes for other house chores.